# PySpark UDF optimization challenge using a dictionary with regex's (Scala?)

Tags: python-3.x, regex, scala, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to optimize the code below (PySpark UDF).

It gives me the desired result (based on my data set) but it's too slow on very large datasets (approx. 180M).

The results (accuracy) are better than available Python modules (e.g. geotext, hdx-python-country). So I'm not looking for another module.

DataFrame:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ["3030 Whispering Pines Circle, Prosper Texas, US","John"],   
  ["Kalverstraat Amsterdam","Mary"],   
  ["Kalverstraat Amsterdam, Netherlands","Lex"] 
]).toDF("address","name")
```

regex.csv:

```
iso2;keywords
US;\bArizona\b
US;\bTexas\b
US;\bFlorida\b
US;\bChicago\b
US;\bAmsterdam\b
US;\bProsper\b
US;\bUS$
CA;\bAlberta\b
CA;\bNova Scotia\b
CA;\bNova Scotia\b
CA;\bWhitehorse\b
CA;\bCA$
NL;\bAmsterdam\b
NL;\Netherlands\b
NL;\bNL$

......<many, many more>
```

Creating a Pandas DataFrame from `regex.csv`, group by `iso2` and joining the `keywords` (`\bArizona\b|\bTexas\b\bFlorida\b|\bUS$`).

```
df = pd.read_csv(regex.csv, sep=';')
df_regex = df.groupby('iso2').agg({'keywords': '|'.join }).reset_index()
```

Function:

```
def get_iso2(x): 
 
    iso2={}
    
    for j, row in df_regex.iterrows():
 
        regex = re.compile(row['keywords'],re.I|re.M)         
        matches = re.finditer(regex, x)
        
        for m in matches:
            iso2[row['iso2']] = iso2.get(row['iso2'], 0) + 1
            
    return [key for key, value in iso2.items() for _ in range(value)]
```

PySpark UDF:

```
get_iso2_udf = F.udf(get_iso2, T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
```

Create new column:

```
df_new = df.withColumn('iso2',get_iso2_udf('address')
```

Expected sample output:

```
[US,US,NL]
[CA]
[BE,BE,AU]
```

Some places occur in more than one country (input is address column with city, province, state, country...)

Sample:

3030  Whispering Pines Circle, Prosper Texas, US -> `[US,US,US]`
Kalverstraat Amsterdam -> `[US,NL]`
Kalverstraat Amsterdam, Netherlands -> `[US, NL, NL]`

Maybe using Scala UDFs in PySpark is an option, but I have no idea how.

Your optimisation recommendations are highly appreciated!

Comment: @anky Edited my question. I'm running a Jupyter Notebook on a Spark cluster using PySpark (Spark DataFrame).

Comment: @anky The regex file pretty much does the trick because it is optimised for my dataset and the result is validated with high accuracy.

Comment: Sounds like you are effectively joining two tables using regexp-like predicate, then grouping on the ID of the first table. You can use `df = df_addresses.crossJoin(df_regex)` to join the two dataframes, then `df.filter(df('address').rlike(df('keywords'))` and then group on the ID column inherited from `df_addresses`. This will run entirely in Spark without marshalling data to and from the Python helper processes.

Comment: @HristoIliev :  I'm not joining tables. Just creating a new column in my spark DataFrame calling the UDF. 
The Pandas DataFrame is only used for joining the keywords from the csv-file creating a long regex-OR for every ISO2. If there's a match the iso2 related to the match(es) is added.

Comment: I said "effectively joining two tables." The first table contains the addresses. The second table contains the ISO code and the corresponding regexp that matches any city/country name for that ISO code. Joining the two and then filtering the rows where the regexp column matches the content address column, then grouping on the address (or the address ID) gives you the list of ISO codes.

Comment: Acutally, you can also join and filter in a single operation like `df_addresses.join(df_regex, df_addresses('address').rlike(df_regex('keywords')), 'cross')`.

Comment: @HristoIliev : Sorry for the misunderstanding. Your intention was lost in translation. 
I now understand what you mean and will try. Marshalling data to and from the Python helper processes is indeed the slowing factor.

Comment: @JohnDoe - it'd be a lot easier to help if you provided code snippets that could be copy / pasted into a PySpark console.  That way I wouldn't need to try to reverse engineer the question into a createDataFrame snippet to created a sample data set ;)

Comment: @JohnDoe - it's a great question and you can make it even better if you add the "I have the following DataFrame" ... "which can be created with this code" [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples).

Comment: @HristoIliev: When I try this `df_addresses.join(df_regex, df_addresses('address').rlike(df_regex('keywords')), 'cross')`I get an error `'DataFrame' object is not callable`. Can you please help.

Comment: Sorry, I've mixed it up with the Scala syntax. Try replacing `df('foo')` with `df.foo`. It will work if there aren't any special or punctuation symbols in `foo` that are not allowed in Python identifiers. Otherwise, use `df['foo']`.

Comment: @HristoIliev : `Pyspark.sql.Column.rlike()` method unfortunately takes only text patterns, not other columns as pattern.

Comment: Yes, I just realised that. In that case, Pandas UDFs are the second best option after Scala UDFs.

Comment: (not spark related) Don't compile the regex on each loop. Put it ouside the loop or provide it as an argument to the function instead. Since the regex is quite big, this should save some time parsing, building, and trowing out a state machine for just one use.

Comment: @Iñigo : I thought about that, but how do I get it done. Can you give an example?

Comment: @JohnDoe - I dont like compiling regexes inside loops. For a simple program maybe moving it to the startup code might do the trick (gist.github.com/igponce/8c083447d38f4715874f3a1a4569fd40). Since you're using Spark, maybe you need to do it in two steps: One job for making the dataframe, compiling the expression, and pickling to a file. And another to unpickle at start and maybe broadcast the df. Also, consider sorting the DF with the regexes by ISO2 with the more frequents first.

Comment: @JohnDoe, you can try: `df_regex = df.groupby('iso2').agg({'keywords':lambda x: re.compile('(?im)' + '|'.join(x))}).reset_index()`. You can do the same to other Python-based functions like  pandas_udf, but do not add this if you use Scala-based functions `split`, `regexp_replace` etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for the additions and examples. I'm going to see if that makes it faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC, you can try the following steps without using UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, first, collect_list, broadcast, monotonically_increasing_id, flatten
import pandas as pd

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ["3030 Whispering Pines Circle, Prosper Texas, US","John"],
  ["Kalverstraat Amsterdam","Mary"],
  ["Kalverstraat Amsterdam, Netherlands","Lex"],
  ["xvcv", "ddd"]
]).toDF("address","name")
```

**Step-1:** convert df_regex to a Spark dataframe `df1` and add an unique_id to `df`.

```
df_regex = pd.read_csv("file:///path/to/regex.csv", sep=";")

# adjust keywords to uppercase except chars preceded with backslash:
df_regex["keywords"] = df_regex["keywords"].str.replace(r'(^|\\.)([^\\]*)', lambda m: m.group(1) + m.group(2).upper())

# create regex patterns:
df_regex = df_regex.groupby('iso2').agg({'keywords':lambda x: '(?m)' + '|'.join(x)}).reset_index()

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df_regex)
df1.show(truncate=False)
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|iso2|keywords                                                                         |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CA  |(?m)\bALBERTA\b|\bNOVA SCOTIA\b|\bWHITEHORSE\b|\bCA$                             |
|NL  |(?m)\bAMSTERDAM\b|\bNETHERLANDS\b|\bNL$                                          |
|US  |(?m)\bARIZONA\b|\bTEXAS\b|\bFLORIDA\b|\bCHICAGO\b|\bAMSTERDAM\b|\bPROSPER\b|\bUS$|
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

df = df.withColumn('id', monotonically_increasing_id())
df.show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------------------------------+----+---+
|address                                        |name|id |
+-----------------------------------------------+----+---+
|3030 Whispering Pines Circle, Prosper Texas, US|John|0  |
|Kalverstraat Amsterdam                         |Mary|1  |
|Kalverstraat Amsterdam, Netherlands            |Lex |2  |
|xvcv                                           |ddd |3  |
+-----------------------------------------------+----+---+
```

**Step-2:** left join df_regex to df using rlike

```
df2 = df.alias('d1').join(broadcast(df1.alias('d2')), expr("upper(d1.address) rlike d2.keywords"), "left")
df2.show()
+--------------------+----+---+----+--------------------+
|             address|name| id|iso2|            keywords|
+--------------------+----+---+----+--------------------+
|3030 Whispering P...|John|  0|  US|(?m)\bARIZONA\b|\...|
|Kalverstraat Amst...|Mary|  1|  NL|(?m)\bAMSTERDAM\b...|
|Kalverstraat Amst...|Mary|  1|  US|(?m)\bARIZONA\b|\...|
|Kalverstraat Amst...| Lex|  2|  NL|(?m)\bAMSTERDAM\b...|
|Kalverstraat Amst...| Lex|  2|  US|(?m)\bARIZONA\b|\...|
|                xvcv| ddd|  3|null|                null|
+--------------------+----+---+----+--------------------+
```

**Step-3:** count number of matched `d2.keywords` in `d1.address` by splitting `d1.address` by `d2.keywords`, and then reduce the size of the resulting Array by 1:

```
df3 = df2.withColumn('num_matches', expr("size(split(upper(d1.address), d2.keywords))-1"))
+--------------------+----+---+----+--------------------+-----------+
|             address|name| id|iso2|            keywords|num_matches|
+--------------------+----+---+----+--------------------+-----------+
|3030 Whispering P...|John|  0|  US|(?m)\bARIZONA\b|\...|          3|
|Kalverstraat Amst...|Mary|  1|  NL|(?m)\bAMSTERDAM\b...|          1|
|Kalverstraat Amst...|Mary|  1|  US|(?m)\bARIZONA\b|\...|          1|
|Kalverstraat Amst...| Lex|  2|  NL|(?m)\bAMSTERDAM\b...|          2|
|Kalverstraat Amst...| Lex|  2|  US|(?m)\bARIZONA\b|\...|          1|
|                xvcv| ddd|  3|null|                null|         -2|
+--------------------+----+---+----+--------------------+-----------+
```

**Step-4:** use [array_repeat](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_repeat) to repeat the value of `iso2` `num_matches` times (require **Spark 2.4+**):

```
df4 = df3.withColumn("iso2", expr("array_repeat(iso2, num_matches)"))
+--------------------+----+---+------------+--------------------+-----------+
|             address|name| id|        iso2|            keywords|num_matches|
+--------------------+----+---+------------+--------------------+-----------+
|3030 Whispering P...|John|  0|[US, US, US]|(?m)\bARIZONA\b|\...|          3|
|Kalverstraat Amst...|Mary|  1|        [NL]|(?m)\bAMSTERDAM\b...|          1|
|Kalverstraat Amst...|Mary|  1|        [US]|(?m)\bARIZONA\b|\...|          1|
|Kalverstraat Amst...| Lex|  2|    [NL, NL]|(?m)\bAMSTERDAM\b...|          2|
|Kalverstraat Amst...| Lex|  2|        [US]|(?m)\bARIZONA\b|\...|          1|
|                xvcv| ddd|  3|          []|                null|         -2|
+--------------------+----+---+------------+--------------------+-----------+
```

**Step-5:** groupby and do the aggregation:

```
df_new = df4 \
    .groupby('id') \
    .agg(
      first('address').alias('address'),
      first('name').alias('name'),
      flatten(collect_list('iso2')).alias('countries')
)
+---+--------------------+----+------------+
| id|             address|name|   countries|
+---+--------------------+----+------------+
|  0|3030 Whispering P...|John|[US, US, US]|
|  1|Kalverstraat Amst...|Mary|    [NL, US]|
|  3|                xvcv| ddd|          []|
|  2|Kalverstraat Amst...| Lex|[NL, NL, US]|
+---+--------------------+----+------------+
```

**Alternative:** Step-3 can also be handled by Pandas UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pandas import Series
import re

@pandas_udf("int", PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def get_num_matches(addr, ptn):
    return Series([ 0 if p is None else len(re.findall(p,s)) for p,s in zip(ptn,addr) ])

df3 = df2.withColumn("num_matches", get_num_matches(expr('upper(address)'), 'keywords'))
+--------------------+----+---+----+--------------------+-----------+
|             address|name| id|iso2|            keywords|num_matches|
+--------------------+----+---+----+--------------------+-----------+
|3030 Whispering P...|John|  0|  US|(?m)\bARIZONA\b|\...|          3|
|Kalverstraat Amst...|Mary|  1|  NL|(?m)\bAMSTERDAM\b...|          1|
|Kalverstraat Amst...|Mary|  1|  US|(?m)\bARIZONA\b|\...|          1|
|Kalverstraat Amst...| Lex|  2|  NL|(?m)\bAMSTERDAM\b...|          2|
|Kalverstraat Amst...| Lex|  2|  US|(?m)\bARIZONA\b|\...|          1|
|                xvcv| ddd|  3|null|                null|          0|
+--------------------+----+---+----+--------------------+-----------+
```

**Notes:**

1. as pattern-matching with case-insensitive is expensive, we converted all chars of keywords (except anchors or escaped chars like `\b`, `\B`, `\A`, `\z`) to upper case.
2. just a reminder, patterns used in `rlike` and `regexp_replace` are Java-based while in pandas_udf it's Python-based which might have slight differences when setting up patterns in regex.csv.

### Method-2: using pandas_udf

As using join and groupby triggers data shuffling, the above method could be slow. Just one more option for your testing:

```
df_regex = pd.read_csv("file:///path/to/regex.csv", sep=";")

df_regex["keywords"] = df_regex["keywords"].str.replace(r'(^|\\.)([^\\]*)', lambda m: m.group(1) + m.group(2).upper())

df_ptn = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(
    df_regex.groupby('iso2').agg({'keywords':lambda x: '(?m)' + '|'.join(x)})["keywords"].to_dict()
)
df_ptn.value
#{'CA': '(?m)\\bALBERTA\\b|\\bNOVA SCOTIA\\b|\\bNOVA SCOTIA\\b|\\bWHITEHORSE\\b|\\bCA$',
# 'NL': '(?m)\\bAMSTERDAM\\b|\\bNETHERLANDS\\b|\\bNL$',
# 'US': '(?m)\\bARIZONA\\b|\\bTEXAS\\b|\\bFLORIDA\\b|\\bCHICAGO\\b|\\bAMSTERDAM\\b|\\bPROSPER\\b|\\bUS$'}

# REF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists
from operator import iconcat
from functools import reduce
from pandas import Series
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType, flatten

def __get_iso2(addr, ptn):   
   return Series([ reduce(iconcat, [[k]*len(re.findall(v,s)) for k,v in ptn.value.items()]) for s in addr ])

get_iso2 = pandas_udf(lambda x:__get_iso2(x, df_ptn), "array<string>", PandasUDFType.SCALAR)

df.withColumn('iso2', get_iso2(expr("upper(address)"))).show()
+--------------------+----+---+------------+
|             address|name| id|        iso2|
+--------------------+----+---+------------+
|3030 Whispering P...|John|  0|[US, US, US]|
|Kalverstraat Amst...|Mary|  1|    [NL, US]|
|Kalverstraat Amst...| Lex|  2|[NL, NL, US]|
|                xvcv| ddd|  3|          []|
+--------------------+----+---+------------+
```

Or return an array of arrays in pandas_udf (w/o `reduce` and `iconcat`) and do `flatten` with Spark:

```
def __get_iso2_2(addr, ptn):
    return Series([ [[k]*len(re.findall(v,s)) for k,v in ptn.value.items()] for s in addr ])

get_iso2_2 = pandas_udf(lambda x:__get_iso2_2(x, df_ptn), "array<array<string>>", PandasUDFType.SCALAR)

df.withColumn('iso2', flatten(get_iso2_2(expr("upper(address)")))).show()
```

**Update:** to find unique countries, do the following:

```
def __get_iso2_3(addr, ptn):
  return Series([ [k for k,v in ptn.value.items() if re.search(v,s)] for s in addr ])

get_iso2_3 = pandas_udf(lambda x:__get_iso2_3(x, df_ptn), "array<string>", PandasUDFType.SCALAR)

df.withColumn('iso2', get_iso2_3(expr("upper(address)"))).show()
+--------------------+----+--------+
|             address|name|    iso2|
+--------------------+----+--------+
|3030 Whispering P...|John|    [US]|
|Kalverstraat Amst...|Mary|[NL, US]|
|Kalverstraat Amst...| Lex|[NL, US]|
|                xvcv| ddd|      []|
+--------------------+----+--------+
```

### Method-3: use a list comprehension:

Similar to **@CronosNull's** method, In case the list of regex.csv is manageable, you can handle this using a list comprehension:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import size, split, upper, col, array, expr, flatten

df_regex = pd.read_csv("file:///path/to/regex.csv", sep=";")
df_regex["keywords"] = df_regex["keywords"].str.replace(r'(^|\\.)([^\\]*)', lambda m: m.group(1) + m.group(2).upper())
df_ptn = df_regex.groupby('iso2').agg({'keywords':lambda x: '(?m)' + '|'.join(x)})["keywords"].to_dict()

df1 = df.select("*", *[ (size(split(upper(col('address')), v))-1).alias(k) for k,v in df_ptn.items()])

df1.select(*df.columns, flatten(array(*[ expr("array_repeat('{0}',`{0}`)".format(c)) for c in df_ptn.keys() ])).alias('iso2')).show()
+--------------------+----+---+------------+
|             address|name| id|        iso2|
+--------------------+----+---+------------+
|3030 Whispering P...|John|  0|[US, US, US]|
|Kalverstraat Amst...|Mary|  1|    [NL, US]|
|Kalverstraat Amst...| Lex|  2|[NL, NL, US]|
|                xvcv| ddd|  3|          []|
+--------------------+----+---+------------+
```

Comment: I'l give it a try. Looks promising and with explanations!

Comment: Step 2: I don't have expected matches `df2 = df.alias('d1').join(broadcast(df1.alias('d2')), expr("d1.address rlike d2.keywords"), "left")` I changed it to `df2 = df.alias('d1').join(broadcast(df1.alias('d2')), expr("d1.address rlike d2.keywords"), "cross")` and it already looks much better. I'll continue testing and keep you updated.

Comment: I forgot to add the (?im) flags to the beginning of the pattern in rlike: `d1.address rlike '(?im)'||d2.keywords`. ideally, this should be handled in df1. Another suggestion is that the case-sensitive matches using `i` flag are often expensive, it would be better to convert all chars in keywords into UPPER case in df1, remove the (i) flag. and do regexp operations on `UPPER(address)` instead.

Comment: made some adjustments based on the comments, see Step-1 and Notes at the end.

Comment: I've made the adjustments and it's running. Is it useful to do a repartition ?

Comment: it depends on your cluster resource and the data size, if the default 200 shuffle.partitions is not enough, just adjust it at the beginning of your code, i.e.  `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1000)`.  IMO there is no point to do repartition in the code. Also bear in mind that a regex pattern with a large list of alternations itself can be very slow. sorting the sub-patterns so that the most frequently seen sub patterns located to the front of the final pattern are usually good practice, I suggest you test on a smaller dataset to verify the method before moving to the large one

Comment: `regexp_replace` in Step-3 is redundant, this can be handled directly using `split` alone. check the updated code with df3

Comment: I've made the adjustments and it's running on a smaller set (100_000)

Comment: Due to technical problems I have to postpone the tests. I appreciate your help and hope to be able to start testing again as soon as possible.

Comment: Used a set of 2000000 records (same test table). My solution:`Wall time:15min 52s` Your solution :`Wall time:15min 53s`

Comment: @JohnDoe, this is most likely an issue from data shuffling in both Step-2 and Step-5 (which might be worse than data SerDes between Python and Java interpreters), especially in a network environment which is inevitable for most big data projects. In the current case, can you set `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` to a smaller number (i.e. `10` ) for testing.

Comment: I added one more solution using pandas_udf under `Method-2` section, can you check if that makes some improvement to the plain udf.

Comment: Yes, I'll check that one as well.

Comment: `sc.broadcast` is giving me an error. Already tried `from pyspark import SparkContext
sc =SparkContext()`

Comment: if you have spark Session, can you try `sc = spark.sparkContext`

Comment: sorry, made a mistake with a capital 's' for sparkContext.

Comment: Very nice ;-) `Wall time: 7mins 45s`

Comment: I'll check your method-3 as well.  It will be difficult to decide which answer to accept. I really appreciate your patience and contribution. Because of the extra explanation, this is also very educational for me.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because of the more extensive explanation and the more flexible method. It was a difficult choice because @CronosNull also helped me very well and his solution is sometimes even a bit faster. Thank you again for the time and patience!

Comment: How can i get unique values for Method-2. I use this method also for another regex and now I need unique values.

Comment: @JohnDoe, updated, check the `Update` section at the end of Method-2

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** Edited based on the comments

I like @jxc's approach. I took a slightly different way, still without using UDFs, and without the need to broadcast the regex dataset (you only use it in the driver).

### Setup the scenario

```
import re
from io import StringIO
from pyspark.sql.functions import (
    split,
    regexp_replace,
    regexp_extract,
    col,
    size,
    concat,
    lit,
    when,
    array,
    expr,
    array_repeat,
    regexp_extract,
    array_join,
)
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ["3030 Whispering Pines Circle, Prosper Texas, US","John"],   
  ["Kalverstraat Amsterdam","Mary"],   
  ["Kalverstraat Amsterdam, Netherlands","Lex"] 
]).toDF("address","name")

sample_data = r"""iso2;keywords
US;\bArizona\b
US:\bTexas\b
US:\bFlorida\b
US;\bChicago\b
US:\bAmsterdam\b
US;\bProsper\b
US;\bUS$
CA:\bAlberta\b
CA:\bNova Scotia\b
CA:\bNova Scotia\b
CA;\bWhitehorse\b
CA;\bCA$
NL:\bAmsterdam\b
NL:\bNetherlands\b
NL;\bNL$"""
replace_pd = pd.read_csv(StringIO(sample_data),delimiter='[;:]', engine='python')
#Resample to have a similar number of rows
replace_pd = replace_pd.append([replace_pd]*10000)
```

### Create a new column by each row of the regex dictionary

```py
def replace_dict(df: DataFrame, column: str, replace_pd: pd.DataFrame)->DataFrame:
    """
    returns a dataframe with the required transformations 
    to have a list of iso2 codes, and its number of repeats, based on the column (e.g. address) selected
    """
    _df = (
        df.withColumn("words", col(column))
    )
    #For each row in the csv create a new column
    # it will contains the new value if the original
    # column contains a matching string. 
    i = 0
    cols = []
    #grouping by iso2 code
    grouped_df = replace_pd.groupby('iso2').agg({'keywords':lambda x: '(?im)' + '|'.join(x)}).reset_index()
    for index, row in grouped_df.iterrows():
        key = row.keywords
        value = row.iso2
        _cr = value
        _df = _df.withColumn(_cr, size(split(col("words"), f"({key})"))-1)
        cols.append(_cr)
        i += 1
    # Join the aux columns, removing the empty strings. 
    _df = _df.withColumn("iso2", array(*[when(col(x)>0,concat(lit(x),lit(":"),col(x))) for x in cols])).withColumn(
        "iso2", expr(r"filter( iso2, x->x NOT rlike '^\s*$')")
    )
    _df = _df.drop("words",*cols) #drop the aux columns.
    return _df
```

#### run the test

```py
replace_dict(df,'address', replace_pd).show(truncate=False)
```

This gives you as a result:

```
+--------------------+----+------------+
|             address|name|        iso2|
+--------------------+----+------------+
|3030 Whispering P...|John|      [US:3]|
|Kalverstraat Amst...|Mary|[NL:1, US:1]|
|Kalverstraat Amst...| Lex|[NL:2, US:1]|
+--------------------+----+------------+
```

It should be faster than other alternatives (all transformations are narrow), but it depends on the size of your regex.csv file (as it creates lots of sparse columns).

Comment: Many thanks. I continue testing @jxc's approach and then I start with yours. The regex.csv is quite large (all countries)

Comment: `regex.csv` separator is all semicolon. Well noticed !!

Comment: Due to technical problems I have to postpone the tests. I appreciate your help and hope to be able to start testing again as soon as possible

Comment: It's been running for a while now but I don't see any job in Spark UI. Only 1 active driver and 1 dead executor. Regex.csv contains 164.059 lines

Comment: Iterate over the pandas' data frame is very costly... if we combine this with the @jxc's idea of grouping the expressions we will get way better results. 
I'll test and come back :)

Comment: Ok, using https://gist.github.com/cronosnull/c6f243b0f2d717103b628e4b41342653 we get a way better result, but you may need to modify it to have the duplicates count if you need it (I guess you do).

Comment: Need to find an illegal character in my regex ...Python / Java issue?. I don't have this error in my script or @jxc

Comment: Why are you replacing `\b` ? `keywords_wob = keywords.replace(r"\b", "")`

Comment: It was because I had tokenized the string by any non-word character, but actually those steps are not necessary (they were part of an early attempt) 
I just updated the gist, let me know if you still have the problem with the regex: https://gist.github.com/cronosnull/c6f243b0f2d717103b628e4b41342653

Comment: Finished without errors `Wall time: 6mins 38s` For all tests I added a repartition of 2000. Without repartition, I only had a limited number of executors and it was much slower.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220269/discussion-between-cronosnull-and-john-doe).

Comment: I've accepted @jxc's answer because of the more extensive explanation and the more flexible method. It was a difficult choice because you also helped me very well and your solution is sometimes even a bit faster. Thank you again for the time and patience!

Comment: Totally agree, I really like how he rewrite the alternative using list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to broadcast `df_regex` to all nodes in the cluster, so each core can process the data in parallel.

```py
df_regex_b = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(df_regex)
```

Update `get_iso2` to use the broadcasted variable:

```py
def get_iso2(x, df_regex_b): 
 
    iso2={}
    
    for j, row in df_regex_b.value.iterrows():
 
        regex = re.compile(row['keywords'],re.I|re.M)         
        matches = re.finditer(regex, x)
        
        for m in matches:
            iso2[row['iso2'] = iso2.get(row['iso2'], 0) + 1
            
    return [key for key, value in iso2.items() for _ in range(value)]
```

Define the UDF with a nested function:

```py
def get_iso2_udf(mapping):
    def f(x):
        return get_iso2(x, mapping)
    return F.udf(f)
```

Comment: Many thanks. I currently have a job running, but as soon as it is ready I'll give it a try.. Indeed I want to broadcast `df_regex` to all nodes in the cluster.  I was under the impression that this was already happening.

Comment: It's running. I've assumed that i have to change `mapping` to `df_regex_b` and  `return F.udf(f)` to `return F.udf(f, T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))`

Comment: Unfortunately it's not faster.

Comment: It is slow because the data in each partition is marshalled from the JVM to a helper Python process and there a `for` loop is performed. Python loops aren't the fastest thing around, which is why one should aim to write Pandas UDFs. But even Pandas UDFs are slow compared to doing everything inside the JVM.